# Force rails log output to defined log file when using hodel_3000_compliant_logger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, torquebox

I'm running `hodel_3000_compliant_logger` (due to needing syslog style output) and have found that when I deploy this to TorqueBox it ends up emitting log output to the TorqueBox JBoss server console log.  Normally TorqueBox just treats logging normally and it shows up in `log/production.log`, but `hodel_3000_compliant_logger` appears to redirect this output to stdout or stderr, which in turn is captured by JBoss.

How can one control `hodel_3000_compliant_logger` output to force it to use the standard rails logging location?